# "Operation could not be completed" after adding App Transport Security to watchkit app

Tags: ios, watchkit

After adding this to the info.plist of the Watchkit app:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

I get the folloging when trying to get it to run on the simulator.

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)
```

I cleaned the build, reset all simulators and emptied the "Derived Build" folder. No avail.

Comment: You use `NSURLSession `?  `NSURLConnection ` ?

Comment: I am using AFNetwork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is answer

[WatchOS 2: "Cannot Install Watch App" "Error Launching 'TestApp WatchKit App Extension'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641162/watchos-2-cannot-install-watch-app-error-launching-testapp-watchkit-app-ext)

Put this key in WatchOS extension info.plist instead of WatchOS App plist.